# Is there any work around to avoid calling /refresh to reload the properties in client spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I learnt about spring-boots config-server and config-client approach. But here every time, I have to call refresh POST API when I do some changes in my properties to reflect in client which I want to avoid it. Can we call the refresh internally in code but not externally?.

Please help.

Comment: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/reloadedable-properties-file-spring-using-apache-commons-configuration/

Comment: sure you can use a scheduled task to call refresh endpoint internally, but i'm not sure that is what you want, because that will reload your application context, which means your application will be done.. but you can try the `STOP file` approach from unix system

Comment: Which backend are you using?

Answer (score 5):

You can save this problem via **Spring Cloud Bus** as described in [official documentation](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_push_notifications_and_spring_cloud_bus). Also, you could use [this](http://tech.asimio.net/2017/02/02/Refreshable-Configuration-using-Spring-Cloud-Config-Server-Spring-Cloud-Bus-RabbitMQ-and-Git.html) blog entry as a step by step guide.

Another solution is less exotic but still valid. You can configure your service to call `RefreshEndpoint.refresh()` periodically as discussed in [this](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/138) topic.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it manually with `ContextRefresh` when you want to reload properties from spring cloud server.

```
@Autowired
ContextRefresher contextRefresher;

public void yourMethod() {
    contextRefresher.refresh();
}
```

Just call `yourMethod` whenever you want.